# Scrollable Layout with a list embedded

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I'm trying to create a scrollable layout with an embedded list, similar to the Spotify application for Android one shown [here](http://cf.scdn.co/u/wp/now-playing3.jpg) (One image at the top followed by a list and the whole layout scrolls). I'm aware that the Android developer guidelines state that you shouldn't put a ListView inside of a ScrollView layout so I'm wondering how this is accomplished. Do I need to make each list item manually using layouts and TextViews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes as the List view has default scroll able functionality . If you place a listview inside the scroll view . The list scroll will hamper.

To Avoid such thing , list view has the concepts of header and footer views.

You can add n number of header and footers to the list.

Below is a sample code snippet how to add header/footer by inflating any xml layout to it

```
LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
LinearLayout listFooterView = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.footer_layout, null);

list.addFooterView(listFooterView);


LinearLayout listHeaderView = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.header_layout, null);

    list.addHeaderView(listHeaderView);
```